# Is there a simpler way to derefence nullable references in Java?

Tags: java, coding-style, nullpointerexception

Consider the following Code Snippet:

```
if (foo != null
 && foo.bar != null
 && foo.bar.boo != null
 && foo.bar.boo.far != null)
{
    doSomething (foo.bar.boo.far);
}
```

My question is simple: is there a more simple\shorter way to do this ?

In detail: is there a more simple way to validate each part of the chain, I'd imagine similar to this ..

```
if (validate("foo.bar.boo.far"))
{
    doSomething (foo.bar.boo.far);
}
```

Comment: See 'The law of demeter' ...

Comment: 'try{doSomething(foo.bar.boo.far);}catch(NullPointerException e){}' doesn't count I guess?:)

Comment: Probably depends on how common null entries are, would get very expensive very quickly

Comment: Your first snippet is clear and to the point. If you really do need to compare four nested objects with null, there is no simpler way. The second snippet, which has code in a string, is frightening. It would not be an improvement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe like that ?

```
if (FooUtils.isFarNotEmpty(foo)){
    doSomething (foo.bar.boo.far);
}
```

and in `FooUtils` :

```
boolean isFarNotEmpty (Foo foo){
   return foo != null && 
          foo.bar != null && 
          foo.bar.boo != null && 
          foo.bar.boo.far != null;
}
```

Comment: Almost same answer I was about to write :) , almost same name too!!

Comment: @JoshuaBarr It's using the Utility-Class pattern

Comment: Putting the uglyness in a method may improve readability a little, but it's a whitewash. Hiding the smelly code like this is avoiding the root cause of it. It should still make you uncomfortable.

Comment: @JoshuaBarr with time you will learn, someone have to do the dirty work .. but check the solution I added below, it's a software engineer suggestion

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion this expression is perfect, nothing can be simpler

Comment: I disagree.  This is more verbose than anyone would like, tedious to write and a pain to maintain.  It's close to the best you can do in Java, but it's an eyesore.

Comment: @tieTYT your solution uses exceptions to control flow, which I think is much worse than a little verbosity. try/catch should not be substituted for an if statement.

Comment: @JoshuaBarr 1) That is not a reason for why this expression is perfect 2) In general I agree, but I feel I gave a reason for when it is worth violating.  If you disagree with that reason, please let me know why

Comment: @tieTYT I think most people would agree such a strange if clause is a symptom of a bigger problem. But given the constraints, the if statement seems like the best that can be done. I gave my reason for this belief (don't use exceptions to control flow), but it's obviously subjective.

Comment: @JoshuaBarr That is not a reason.  That's dogmatism.

Comment: @tieTYT, also, catching `NullPointerException` as you do is problematic, because it will catch an NPE thrown by `doSomething`, which is not the intended effect.

Comment: @JoshuaBarr That's a good reason.  Fortunately for the example I gave, it was not an issue.

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer Who are you replying to?

Answer (score 1):

why you are using public instance variable, encapsulate your public variables and create getter  and setter for them and you can perform these check in your getter, and you can return new Object() if any of them is null, or you can run this statement in try-catch block but not recommended,

Comment: if any part of the chain is NULL, I don't want to doSomething()

Comment: As NullPointerException is type of RuntimeException and they should never be catched although it is shortening your code but is bad practice and against standard, what code you posted in your code is fine and you are good to go with it.

Comment: Why should I throw an Exception, when I'm already trying to avoid it ?.. My code is good, but I asked for a shorter way

Comment: Read my post again i have mentioned it is not good practice to catch RuntimeException

Answer (score 1):

If this is your API please [consider some advice](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained).

> "I call it my billion-dollar mistake." - Sir C. A. R. Hoare, on his
>   invention of the null reference

Comment: You can never be sure it won't be null

Comment: In this model every nullpointer is a bug. Given this assumption you can trust your type system again that a type A is really an A not null.

Comment: You know why NullPointerException is a run-time Exception ? Because you never know if it will occur before executing the code

Comment: I'd say it's a run-time exception because trying to dereference a NP is a programmer error. If you allow null values it's a user error if not it's an error of the code returning null values.

Comment: You are making an assumption of how I worked on the context in which I could place that example .. Reality is I work on an Enterprise system that was already build before I work on it, also the system I work on use database, and it depends on data that has infinite possibilities of making the business logic go wrong, but it's not my job to check for everything

Answer (score 0):

There's not much you can do with this, unfortunately.  If you ask me, it's a problem with the Java language.  Groovy has something called the [Safe Navigation Operator ?.](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Operators#Operators-SafeNavigationOperator) that is specifically for this purpose.  Here are two things I've done in the past.

1. The answer that Grisha already gave, so I won't repeat it
2. Naively wrote code that accesses it, and surround it in a try/catch for a NPE.  Here's an example:

   ```
   try {
       if (foo.bar.boo.far != null) {
           //do something
       }
   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       //do what you would do in an else
   }
   ```

I don't particularly like the 2nd option, but I say if it actually makes the code cleaner, consider using it.

One time I was working with a library that is a very thin wrapper over an XML schema and I decided to use the 2nd option for this case.  If I didn't, the code would have been harder to maintain because it would be so easy to forget a null check and they cluttered up the important logic.  I think that's a valid case for using it.

Comment: I'm trying not to doSomething() in case any part of the chain is NULL, getting an Exception for that possibility will make your code worse than my example

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer: In my code, you won't call `doSomething()` if any of the chain are null.  If this is the one place in your code you've got an if statement like this, then I'm not recommending 2. either.  But if you've got code like this all over the place, like I did, it may make your code cleaner.

Comment: But if an exception is thrown when I'm already planning to avoid it, that's awkward

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
try {
    if (foo.bar.boo.far != null) {
        //No object is null
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // some object is null and causes null point exception.
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but if an exception is thrown when I'm already planning to avoid it, that's awkward